# How to connect with google api

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-api

For my application i need to get the hotels nearby using GOOGLE API.
How can i connect my application with GOOGLE API for getting the images from google?
From the google database i have to access the images of the hotels and so that i could find out is there any rooms are available or not......
Is it possible or is there any other methods available? 
How can it be done?
Actually i added the JSON parser class files to my code,but then i couldn't find out how to get the images from the google.

thanks for the code!!!!